# DateTime, .AddSeconds() not working?

Tags: c#, datetime

I've been scratching my head over this one for a couple hours now, I've drafted in co-workers and we are all lost.  This could be a case of too much coffee from the new espresso machine, or the fact it's Friday... We're not sure!

I have the following method:

```
private void calcuateEstimatedExecutionTimesForDueJobs(List<TestJob> dueJobs)
{
    DateTime rollingTime = DatabaseConnection.getNow();

    foreach (TestJob job in dueJobs)
    {
        job.setEstimatedStart(rollingTime);

        double estimatedRuntime = job.getEstimatedRuntime();

        rollingTime = rollingTime.AddSeconds(estimatedRuntime);

        job.setEstimatedFinish(rollingTime);
    }
}
```

The intention is to process a list of "TestJobs" which our app is queued to deliver.  Our TestJob kindly knows how long it will "probably" take to run so I hope to use this information here to predict the "Start" & "Finish" times of each TestJob.

Unfortunately, rollingTime is never altered.  Although job.getEstimatedRuntime() always returns a positive double, calling AddSeconds() on the current TestJob and passing this value has no effect.

Is there a bug in my code, or something more sinister?

**Update:** I noticed that this question is still getting a few views.  For those of you suffering an odd issue like mine, I remember resolving this one by simply **restarting Visual Studio / Rebooting**.  I guess this issue still crops up from time to time... (Ahem...)!

Comment: Looks OK, are you sure estimatedRuntime is not 0?

Comment: Is it a very small positive double?  DateTime only has resolution down to a few milliseconds.  If it's less than that...

Comment: I ran a test case with your structure, just using dummy values, and it worked.  So, double check that however you're checking that `rollingTime` is changing is working correctly, and double check the values that you're adding.

Comment: estimatedRuntime cannot return < 1.

Typical examples of what it does return are: 35, 55.25, 63, 12.8

Comment: Is it at all possible this is a scope problem? Is this the only place where rollingTime is declared? Sometimes I'll accidentally turn an assignment into a declaration and have a problem just like this.

Comment: is it possible your setEstimatedStart or setEstimatedFinish have a bug? Have you tried looking at it in the debugger or logging?

Comment: Did you debug it step by step? Before the line "rollingTime = rollingTime.AddSeconds(estimatedRuntime);" executes, check if estimatedRuntime really has a value, and after the line is executed, check if rollingTime has changed. If it hasn't, that would be really weird.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

I've stepped through this with a debugger, and I know for absolute that job.getEstimatedRuntime(); is returning expected values.  In fact, the 4 I gave in an earlier comment were actual results.

As per the scope suggestion, thanks - hadn't thought about that tbh.  Sadly it's not that; this is the only place in my whole solution I use that name.

Comment: And did you check that rollingTime gets updated correctly (or not) after AddSeconds??

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of the code for the TestJob class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a small test program based on your code:

```
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      List<TestJob> jobList = new List<TestJob>();

      jobList.Add(new TestJob() { ID = 1 });
      jobList.Add(new TestJob() { ID = 2 });
      jobList.Add(new TestJob() { ID = 3 });
      jobList.Add(new TestJob() { ID = 4 });

      CalcuateEstimatedExecutionTimesForDueJobs(jobList);

      foreach (TestJob job in jobList)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", job.ID, job.StartDate, job.FinishedDate);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CalcuateEstimatedExecutionTimesForDueJobs(List<TestJob> dueJobs)
    {
      DateTime rollingTime = DateTime.Now;

      foreach (TestJob job in dueJobs)
      {
        job.SetEstimatedStart(rollingTime);

        double estimatedRuntime = job.GetEstimatedRuntime();
        rollingTime = rollingTime.AddSeconds(estimatedRuntime);

        job.SetEstimatedFinish(rollingTime);
      }
    }
  }

  public class TestJob
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinishedDate { get; set; }
    public void SetEstimatedStart(DateTime date)
    {
      this.StartDate = date;
    }
    public void SetEstimatedFinish(DateTime date)
    {
      this.FinishedDate = date;
    }

    public double GetEstimatedRuntime()
    {
      return 42; //Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything
    }

  }
```

Reveals that everything works as expected. The console output is:

```
1 02.10.2009 17:08:43 02.10.2009 17:09:25
2 02.10.2009 17:09:25 02.10.2009 17:10:07
3 02.10.2009 17:10:07 02.10.2009 17:10:49
4 02.10.2009 17:10:49 02.10.2009 17:11:31
```

Which is, as far as I can tell correct.
Please double check your dependent code in your TestJob class and debug / log everything.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can confirm that this sample program works as I wish my method would! :)

Back to head-scratching.

Comment: You're effort was appreciated.  I used this code to help me solve the problem.  For which I still do not really know what caused it! Regardless I am a firm believer of effort = reward, which is why I am accepting this as my answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

OBS: ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds(v=vs.110).aspx

This method does not change the value of this DateTime. Instead, it returns a new DateTime whose value is the result of this operation.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That should work without any problems.

I suggest you try to convert the question into a [short but complete program which demonstrates the problem](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/complete.html). You might also want to add some logging in - log `rollingTime` and 
 `estimatedRuntime` on each iteration.

Btw, any reason why you're using Java conventions in C#?

Comment: You've caught me!  I'm new to c#, with a background in Java.  I'll mock up a small program to see if I can replicate this bug elsewhere.

Comment: Just copy/paste my example and you're half way there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added logging and observed the results I was expecting.  I removed the logging and still saw the results expected.  I have no idea what this was or where it came from but the problem is rectified.  Glitch in the matrix?

Comment: "Glitch in the matrix", or just an ordinary day...  ;)